# DC Printer motor to AC

Tags: motor, ac, dc, dc-motor, wiring

I know a little about electronics but I don't know that much and always happy to learn.

I have an HP printer that I am using in DIY project. It as one large motor (24v from what I have read online) and one small motor (no markings and I am guessing 12v plus).

[image]
[image]

What I need to know is what is the best way to connect the motor to ac to run-off the mains.

Comment: Transformer, rectifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still have the original printer power supply shown in your photo (which puts out 32VDC at up to 625mA) then you just need a DC/DC step-down regulator to reduce the voltage, like this:-

[5A DC-DC Adjustable Step-Down Buck Power Converter Module DC 5-36V to 1.2V-32V with LED Voltmeter](http://www.icstation.com/adjustable-step-down-buck-power-converter-module-with-voltmeter-p-10528.html)

[image]

If you want to vary the motor speed then get a PWM controller like this:-

[Micro DC3V~35V 5A PWM DC Motor Speed Controller](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Micro-DC3V-35V-5A-PWM-DC-Motor-Speed-Controller-Adjustable-Switch-LED-Dimmer-90W-/282503348379?epid=929966441&hash=item41c683009b:g:VfYAAOSw7GRZKUR2)

[image]